# Finding zeros in a goniometric function

Tags: roots

I need to find the zeros (roots?) of a function e.g. $$x-\sin(2x)$$ in the interval $[0,\pi]$
so that would make
 $$\sin(2x) = x$$

I've already found $0$ but I can't find a way to determine the other one

Comment: Can you use numerical methods?

Comment: no, just plain discrete math

Comment: What do you mean with "find the zeros"? Find some interval that contains exactly one zero, compute an approximating sequence, or something else?

Comment: finding all the solutions in the interval $[0,\pi]$  for which $x - sin(2x) = 0$ in this case

Comment: @Wouter, what do you mean by "discrete mathematics" here? This is very much a *continuous* problem, a trascendental equation that has no solution in terms of elementary functions.

Answer (score 0):

As $\sin 2x\approx 2x $ for $x\approx 0$ you know that 
$$
\sin(2x)>x
$$
on some interval right of $x=0$. More precisely, by alternating series properties
$$\sin (2x)\ge 2x-\frac{(2x)^3}6=x\left(2-\frac{4x^2}3\right)$$
for $|x|<1$, so that you can take $x_1=\frac34$.

For $x>1$ you know that $$\sin(2x)\le 1<x.$$

Combined this means that there is a root of the equation in
$$
x\in\left[\frac34,1\right].
$$
Now check the derivatives over this interval to conclude that there is exactly one root because of monotonicity.